# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException" [50000-214]

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am creating an application using Springboot. I am using H2 database as a dependency of version 2.1.214. I am getting below error-

```
2022-07-26 17:38:24.039  INFO 5308 --- [           main] c.e.E.EmployeeApplication                : Starting EmployeeApplication using Java 17.0.4 on DESKTOP-2NJA7RF with PID 5308 (E:\SpringBoot Projects\EmployeeApplication\target\classes started by HP in E:\SpringBoot Projects\EmployeeApplication)
2022-07-26 17:38:24.039  INFO 5308 --- [           main] c.e.E.EmployeeApplication                : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-07-26 17:38:25.334  INFO 5308 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-07-26 17:38:25.427  INFO 5308 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 80 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-07-26 17:38:26.521  INFO 5308 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-07-26 17:38:26.536  INFO 5308 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-07-26 17:38:26.536  INFO 5308 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-07-26 17:38:26.724  INFO 5308 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-07-26 17:38:26.724  INFO 5308 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2566 ms
2022-07-26 17:38:26.849  INFO 5308 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-07-26 17:38:27.993 ERROR 5308 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException" [50000-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:554) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
```

I can't understand what it means. I have searched the stack overflow about Hikaripool, but was unable to find a solution for this issue.
The application.properties are-

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:course-library-management-system;MV_STORE=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

The pom.xml dependencies are-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.employee</groupId>
    <artifactId>EmployeeApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EmployeeApplication</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.214</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove `MV_STORE=FALSE` from JDBC connection URL, there is no such setting in H2 2.*.*. These versions have only MVStore-based backed.

Comment: thanks for rectifying my mistake.